# How to get event.preventDefault to work on dynamic function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that is split into sections. When the user clicks "continue", I have a jquery script that checks to see if all required fields are filled out. If any aren't, then a box appears with a warning and buttons (They are actually `<a>` tags) for 'yes' and 'no'. I attach an onclick event to the 'yes' button that triggers a function. The function works, but a # appears in the address bar (website.com/page#), which I'm guessing is because the `event.preventDefault();` in my code isn't working.

Here is the function that adds the onclick event:

```
function checkSection (event, check, goTo) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var emptyFields = "0";
    $("#ia"+check+"Div .check").each(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();

        if (val == "") {
            emptyFields++;
        } 
    });

    if (emptyFields >= 1) {
        $(".mask").show();
        $("#warningBox").show();
        $(document).on("click", "#yesBtn", function() { 
            var x = window['save'+check];
            x(event, goTo);
            $("#warningBox").hide();
            $(".mask").hide();
        });
    } else {
        var x = window['save'+check];
        x(event, goTo);
        $("#warningBox").hide();
    }
}
```

Here is the  tag I am adding the event to:

```
<div class="medBtn short">
    <div class="btnTbl">
        <a href="#" id="yesBtn">Yes</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The function I end up calling is like this:

```
function saveContact(event, val) {
    event.preventDefault();

   //Do Stuff - This is the function where event.preventDefault(); isn't working
}
```

Like I said, the function still works, so if it's not something I can get around, that is fine. I just don't like having a # in the address bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event object doesn't exist until the event occurs

You prevent default inside the actual event handler

```
$(document).on("click", "#yesBtn", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ....
})
```